# How does vim-pathogen make anything easier?

Tags: vim

If I understand it correctly, with pathogen it makes things easy because all you have to do to install/uninstall plugins is place or remove the plugin from a certain directory.

But isn't this what the plugin directory is for? How is it any better?

Answer (score 16):

A plugin can be a single `plugin_name.vim` file that you toss into `~/.vim/plugin/`. If every plugins were single files we wouldn't "need" any plugin management solutions.

But most plugins are actually collections of files that need to be placed in certain directories like `~/.vim/autoload/`, `~/.vim/after/`, `~/.vim/doc/` and so on. This has been considered "messy" for a while and Pathogen is one of many answers to this problem:

- Vimball `:help vimball`
- [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle)
- [VAM](http://packages.debian.org/sid/vim-addon-manager)
- [VAM](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager)
- [Unbundle](https://github.com/sunaku/vim-unbundle)
- possibly others…

If you don't think that it's a problem then you obviously don't need a solution (pathogen or whatever).

I think that it's a problem (I like my things well organized), Pathogen is the first solution I came across and it served me well.

Answer (score 6):

It's better because you can store your plugin in isolation in the `~/.vim/bundle` directory. That makes easier for you to have all your configuration directory under a version control system. Take a look at my [vimfiles](https://github.com/lucapette/vimfiles) for example.

All the plugins I use are stored as a git [submodule](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1%20git-submodule) and this makes updates easy to handle. Furthermore, if you want to remove a plugin it's just a matter of removing the relative directory in the bundle one.

Comment: Plus, if you want to uninstall a plugin, you don't have to hunt all it's files - you just need to delete it's folder(and submodule, if you use git)